# Generate BarCode on Watch OS 2

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

How do i generate a barcode on apple watch with Watch OS2, i can do it using API's like ZXing on iOS, but i wonder is there a way  to do the same in watchOS2

```
NSError *error = nil;
ZXMultiFormatWriter *writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];
ZXBitMatrix* result;
//generate code 128 barcode
result= [writer encode:barCodeNumber
                    format:kBarcodeFormatCode128
                     width:500
                    height:500
                     error:&error];
if (result) {
    CGImageRef image = [[ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result] cgimage];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by generating image in iOS app and passing it to watch os using background transfers, by creating NSData from image, something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
if([WCSession isSupported]){
    self.watchSession = [WCSession defaultSession];
    self.watchSession.delegate = self;
    [self.watchSession activateSession];
}
}

   -(void)sendDatatoAppleWatch
{
NSMutableArray*barCodesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
UIImage* barCodeImage=[self generateBarCode];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(barCodeImage);
[barCodeArray addObject:pngData]

    if(self.watchSession){
  NSError *error = nil;
    if(![self.watchSession
         updateApplicationContext:
         @{@"cardData" : userCardsArray }
         error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Updating the context failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);

        UIAlertView* errorAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:error.localizedDescription message:error.debugDescription delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [errorAlert show];  
    }
 }


//*** Apple Watch Code**// 


- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
[super awakeWithContext:context];
if([WCSession isSupported]){
    self.watchSession = [WCSession defaultSession];
    self.watchSession.delegate = self;
    [self.watchSession activateSession];
}
}


- (void) session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)applicationContext {
   NSData* imageData = [[[applicationContext objectForKey:@"cardData"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"barCodeImage"];
   [self.barcodeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate on iOS app, then transfer it to the watch. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: [EFQRCode](https://github.com/EFPrefix/EFQRCode).

As from its doc, the original implementation is from [swift_qrcodejs](https://github.com/ApolloZhu/swift_qrcodejs), which is `Cross-appleOS SIMPLE QRCode generator for swift, without using CIFilter`.